# How to alert on new records in a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table that consists of:

```
   date        time     user       ip
------------------------------------------
2017-12-15   12:22:04   user1   172.16.0.0 
2017-12-15   12:22:10   user2   172.16.0.2
2017-12-15   12:22:25   user1   172.16.0.1 
2017-12-15   12:22:45   user2   172.16.0.2
```

I want to generate an email alert if there is a new record in the table for  `user`  with a new `ip`.

The email alert would be something along the lines of "`user` has logged in from a new `ip  time`".

Do I need to create another table per user to track all the historical `ip` for that user - and alert if a new record with a new `ip` is being?

I can see that getting out of control real quick if there are 200+ users to track so I am seeing if there are better ways to do this.

Comment: Just use a trigger and compare the `inserted` rows to previous ones.

Comment: You definitely need to keep track of IPs that users have been associated with if you want to test if they are logging in from a new IP. But you are already doing that in this table so you don’t need a new table for that.

Comment: You *could* do this with a trigger, HOWEVER, the problem is that if the `sp_send_dbmail` command fails, then your `INSERT` will as well.

Comment: You just need to store the last run date and time, so you can check if there is any new user since last run.

Comment: Divide up the work. You can poll periodically for changes and write the results to a queue and then create another worker to read from the queue and send messages. The two processes are vastly different and need to configured separately.

Comment: @Larnu How? Can't they just `catch` the error from the `dbmail` SP and ignore it and carry on, if it's not fatal?

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way. I would add this logic to your application long before the data hits this table. When you login have the application send the email if the IP is a new one.

Comment: I don't have control to modify the application, I am basically parsing IIS logs and pumping the data into a SQL table so that I can then do something with it.

Comment: @underscore_d you can introduce a `TRY...CATCH`, but it can make things really messy. Ideally triggers should be used for further data manipulation, etc. They shouldn't be used to tasks like sending emails, starting Agent Jobs, etc. Sean has the best idea thus far, I agree, Application level is much better.

Comment: @exxoid you might not have the ability, but someone will. Speak to them in regards to the matter.

Comment: This is IIS logs from Microsoft Exchange. I have better luck winning the lottery than getting MS to make these changes for me.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing an ETL task to do this then. Personally, I would do the ETL into a staging table, check that against the existing data (which should be well Indexed, as it'll get big, quick), send out the relevant emails, and complete the ETL from staging to Production.

Comment: So send the email when you parse the logs. Doing this in a trigger is not the best location.

Comment: I was thinking ETL as well with a stage/production table with some logic to alert in the flow. Seems like such a overkill, was hoping I can roll a stored procedure or something instead.

Comment: You can do this as a trigger.  I would recommend that the trigger load a message to a message queue, and an asynchronous process read the queue and send the email.  You don't want a trigger to be waiting for applications external to the database.

Comment: How would one do this with a trigger? I can wrap my head around ETL because it is all visual; but I am lost when it comes to writing TSQL/Trigger.